# list authors and belonging titles

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select authors (distinct) and for each of them list the belonging titles, not older than six months.

```
$items = '';
$sqla = "select distinct auth from posts order by date";
$sta = $db->prepare($sqla);
$sta -> execute();
while ($rowa = $sta->fetch()) {
    $items .= "<div class='auth'>" . mb_strtoupper($row['auth']) . "</div>\n";
    $sqlb = "select id, date, title, subtitle, tags, from posts where `auth` = '" . $rowa['auth'] . "' and `date` < date(now() - interval 6 month)";
    $stb = $db->prepare($sqlb);
    $stb -> execute(); // line 29
    while ($rowb = $stb->fetch()) {
        $items .= $rowb['title'] . '\n'; 
    }
}

echo $items;
```

Fatal error on line 29.

Comment: This code doesn't look like it has 29 lines

Comment: @Adam, I marked it

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Surely the error is  a little more verbose than simply *Fatal error on line 29* ? No *"Commands out of synch"* or something actually useful to go on?

Comment: @Kyrre `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error...`

Comment: Oh - you've got an additional comma `subtitle, tags, from posts` <- after `tags`

Comment: Maybe the `date` in the `select` part of your query triggers the error by being a reserved keyword. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Kyrre `date` is not reserved, the `(R)` denotes reserved terms.

Comment: Maybe `select group_concat(title) as titles, auth from posts where date <= date(now() - interval 6 month) group by auth` is what you want?

Comment: It also is worth noting that `$rowa['auth']` opens you to second order SQL injection, should parameterize the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do using a single query

```
     select distinct auth,id, date, title, subtitle, tags 
     from posts 
     where  `date` < date(now() - interval 6 month)
     order by date
```

anyway you have an error in your second query  (tags,)   remove the comma before from

```
 $sqlb = "select id, date, title, subtitle, tags from posts where `auth` = '" . $rowa['auth'] . "' and `date` < date(now() - interval 6 month)";
```

and for author you should refer to $rowa

```
$items .= "<div class='auth'>" . mb_strtoupper($rowa['auth']) . "</div>\n";
```

Comment: with the second part of the asnwer you should resolve your error

Comment: I removed the comme and got only titles, without authors

Comment: you echo only the title  .. you should add  the author too .. but this mean that your error is solved ..

Comment: no, I need an author and titles below, then second author and his titles below etc

Comment: for the author in the outer while you should refer to $rowa and for the inner while you should select the auth column too ..

Comment: I'm sure  .. you have select the auth only in the first select  (and you could use this value as $rowa['auth '] ..but if you want auth in $rowb ... you must add to select column  eg:  select id, date, title, subtitle, tags, auth ...  ..

Comment: I don't need autors with each title, only on the top of titles list. but there is no any.

Comment: in your code you are referring to `mb_strtoupper($row['auth'])`  but you have mapped  each row as `$rowa ` so you should use  `mb_strtoupper($rowa['auth'])`    as suggeted  in my answer